# Converting HEIC to JPG on Heroku with imagemagick

Tags: heroku, imagemagick, heic

I have a rails 7 app on heroku 20 stack, I try to conveert heic photo into jpg. I update rmagick  by adding the buildpack with

heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 https://github.com/DuckyTeam/heroku-buildpack-imagemagick.git

now, I have have this error after trying to convert HEIC to jpg

2023-10-25T06:39:16.771988+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2023-10-25T06:39:16.771960 #2] FATAL -- : [c81b3e26-3995-4383-a99d-a72f58d9df31]
2023-10-25T06:39:16.772012+00:00 app[web.1]: [c81b3e26-3995-4383-a99d-a72f58d9df31] MiniMagick::Invalid (`magick identify /tmp/mini_magick20231025-2-eoi3h5` failed with status: 1 and error:
2023-10-25T06:39:16.772013+00:00 app[web.1]: identify: UnableToOpenConfigureFile `delegates.xml' @ warning/configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/715. 2023-10-25T06:39:16.772014+00:00 app[web.1]: identify: NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat` ' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/509.
2023-10-25T06:39:16.772014+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2023-10-25T06:39:16.772015+00:00 app[web.1]: [c81b3e26-3995-4383-a99d-a72f58d9df31]

My code work when it convert png to HEIC,

Comment: I suspect your MiniMagick is try to use Imagemagick 7, but your system only has Imagemagick 6.